# Javascript фильтр по первым буквам слова

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Как при помощи Javascript/jQuery сделать, чтобы при вводе слова в строку поиска, данные внутри `<div>`отфильтровывались по первым буквам? https://jsfiddle.net/0sa40u4f/

Например, мы вводим букву  'А', остаться должны такие имена: 'Анастасия, Александр, Андрей', остальные скрыться.

Если мы введем следующую букву у нас получится словосочетание 'Ан', то останется два имени: 'Анастасия, Андрей'.

И так далее по буквам производится фильтр исходя из имеющихся данных.

```
Маска для поиска: <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
        <div id="name">
          <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Анастасия</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Александр</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Борис</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Андрей</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Павел</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function init(){
  let template = `<li><a href="#">%name</a></li>`,
      search   = document.querySelector('#search'),
      list     = document.querySelector('#list'),
      names    = ['Анастасия', 'Александр', 'Борис', 'Андрей', 'Павел'],
      render   = a => list.innerHTML = a.map(e => template.replace('%name', e)).join(`\n`);
  
  search.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    let value = search.value.toLowerCase();
    
    render(names.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().startsWith(value)));
  });
  render(names);
}

//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
init();
```

```html
Маска для поиска:
<input type="text" ng-model="search" id='search' />
<div id="name">
  <ul id='list'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Судя по атрибуту `ng-model`, используется `AngularJS`.
Тогда я не побоюсь отправить к [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="names = [
    'Анастасия',
    'Александр',
    'Борис',
    'Андрей',
    'Павел'
  ];">
 Маска для поиска: <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
 <div id="name">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
    <a href="#">{{ name }}</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/0sa40u4f/2/).

Comment: пример с ангуляром ищет не по началу строки, а по всей строке

Comment: @Grundy, Вы как всегда наблюдательны. Но главное было о фильтрах напомнить.

Comment: @Other  Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли обойтись без массива  `name`? Потому что данные в выдаче внутри `<li></li>` динамические и всегда разные. Спасибо!

Comment: @Pavel, есть только `names`. Можно и без него - каждый раз обращаться к списку, вытаскивать имена и искать в них, только обращение к DOM - очень дорогое по времени и ресурсам. Золотая середина тут - получить данные в списке (`ul>li`) и добавить их в массив `names`, ради оптимизации.

Comment: @Other, Спасибо за ответ! Получилось поместить в массив, отлично работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли сделать транслитерацию английских букв в русские? Например, если у пользователя стоит английская раскладка, а он вводит русское имя "Fyfcnfcbz"(Анастасия), чтобы это имя выводилось по русски набранными английскими буквами.

Comment: @Pavel, сделать можно, от маппинга, до перевода кода буквы и поиска пары.

Comment: @Other, если можно, могли бы привести пример. Спасибо!

Comment: Пример могу, но не очень люблю тех, кто хочет без попыток сделать что-то сам, получить решение бесплатно от меня. Как Вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: @Other  Решил так  ` var names = []; 
 $('#list a').each( function (key, val) {
 names.push($(val).text());
 });` Спасибо вам за помощь, буду искать решение транслитерации в инете, примеры вроде есть, нужно разобраться.

Comment: @Pavel, я имел ввиду задачу о транслитерации. Пробуйте её решить сами, если будет видно что Вы действительно стремитесь к решению, но вышла ошибка, поверьте, желающих помочь складировать придётся :)

Comment: @Other Здравствуйте! Извините за назойливость, не могли бы помочь преобразовать написанные вами стрелочные функции в обычные?  render   = a => list.innerHTML = a.map(e => template.replace('%name', e)).join(`\n`);     render(names.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().startsWith(value)));

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44378/discussion-between-other-and-pavel).